# Need "Export" link in user list page

Tags: wordpress, plugins, hook, custom-code

I want to add new link called as "Export" on user list page at www.mysamplewebsite.com/wp-admin/users.php page .. and if user clicks on it, it should export all the added users in csv or excel format.

i have searched plugins but all are allowing to do this thing in different menu but as per client's requirements, i need to follow this ..

do we have any wordpress hooks available or anything else from which i can implement this stuff ? i have searched around but yet to find a proper solution according to the wordpress flow..

can someone help me to achieve this thing using any wordpress hook or something ...

looking forward ..

Thanks

Comment: You can use add_users_page, which will add sub menu to user's menu  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_users_page

Comment: i dont need submenu .. i need a link beside the user's count we have in wordpress user's list page .. like this adminitrators(10) editors (15) , Export link [Something like this] on this page  www.mysamplewebsite.com/wp-admin/users.php page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this should do:

```
<?php

/********* Export to csv ***********/
add_action('admin_footer', 'mytheme_export_users');

function mytheme_export_users() {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( $screen->id != "users" )   // Only add to users.php page
        return;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready( function($)
        {
            $('.tablenav.top .clear, .tablenav.bottom .clear').before('<form action="#" method="POST"><input type="hidden" id="mytheme_export_csv" name="mytheme_export_csv" value="1" /><input class="button button-primary user_export_button" style="margin-top:3px;" type="submit" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Export All as CSV', 'mytheme');?>" /></form>');
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}

add_action('admin_init', 'export_csv'); //you can use admin_init as well

function export_csv() {
    if (!empty($_POST['mytheme_export_csv'])) {

        if (current_user_can('manage_options')) {
            header("Content-type: application/force-download");
            header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="users'.date('YmdHis').'.csv"');

            // WP_User_Query arguments
            $args = array (
                'order'          => 'ASC',
                'orderby'        => 'display_name',
                'fields'         => 'all',
            );

            // The User Query
            $blogusers = get_users( $args );
            // Array of WP_User objects.
            foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
                $meta = get_user_meta($user->ID);
                $role = $user->roles;
                $email = $user->user_email;

                $first_name = ( isset($meta['first_name'][0]) && $meta['first_name'][0] != '' ) ? $meta['first_name'][0] : '' ;
                $last_name  = ( isset($meta['last_name'][0]) && $meta['last_name'][0] != '' ) ? $meta['last_name'][0] : '' ;

                echo '"' . $first_name . '","' . $last_name . '","' . $email . '","' . ucfirst($role[0]) . '"' . "\r\n";
            }

            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

The first part will add a button to the table navigation in header and footer of the users table. When you click it you'll call the `export_csv()` function that is below. You can customize it to your liking of course.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)

Comment: Does this all go in functions.php?

Answer (score 0):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/export-user-data/screenshots/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/export-users-data-to-csv/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-export/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/export-users-to-csv/

These plugins will help you what you want to achieve

Comment: i know most of above but my requirement is bit different .. i want link in www.mysamplewebsite.com/wp-admin/users.php page  . like this adminitrators(10) editors (15) , Export link [Something like this]

Comment: instead of new menu altogether